# Gson deserialization setting optional attributes

Tags: deserialization, gson, option-type

I have a scenario where in I have serialized and saved JSON data into a document store. The serialization was done using GSON. Now I have added an additional attribute to the class that has been serialized, so now when I try to deserialize I get an exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 420
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
    com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
```

Looks like this seems to be due to the addition of the new class attribute. Is there anyway of specifying that the new attribute is OPTIONAL so that GSON deserialization would work in this case?

Comment: Are you sure that this depends on the new attribute? Gson does not fail if you serialize a class and then deserialize it with a subclass that extends first with more attributes. Could you post your string, your class and how you deserialize? Your stacktrace seems originated by a not Json string

Comment: Could it be that you have changed the type of a field in your class? Moving from string to a more complex object?

Comment: Not really sure what was going on here. Anyways I removed the optional attribute, from serialization, and things started working again !!